# RigidBody2D AddForce Not Adding Acceleration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I'm trying to add acceleration to an object with a RigidBody2D component using `AddForce`, but all it seems to do is add a fixed velocity instead.

Here are the RigidBody2D settings:
[image: RigidBody2D Settings]

For testing I've modified the `Update` function to allow me to add forces and report the object's velocity periodically:

```cs
void Update()
{
    time += Time.deltaTime;
    if (time > 0.5)
    {
        Debug.Log("Velocity magnitude = " + rigidbody2D.velocity.magnitude);
        time = 0;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
    {
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.right);
    }
}
```

What I see is that every time I press Q, the velocity magnitude increases by a fixed 0.02.

I.e. first it doesn't move at all and the velocity is 0, then after pressing Q the velocity magnitude changes to 0.02 and stays at 0.02 while the object trudges slowly to the right. Pressing Q again increases it to 0.04, then pressing once more increases it to 0.06 and so on.

These are results from two days ago. I did the experiment again today and got different velocity increments but the same behavior otherwise.

The velocity changes **only** when I add a force.

If I added a force of magnitude 1 to an object at rest with a mass of 1 then its velocity would increase by 1 in magnitude every single unit of time (which I think here is seconds).

Instead it's staying fixed.

Using ForceMode2D.Impulse increases the velocity increments from 0.02 to 1, but the behavior stays the same - no acceleration, only one-time increments in speed.

What am I doing wrong?

---

I've tried looking for similar posts and for the problem in general but the only things I found were either irrelevant or asking the opposite (how to stop acceleration from occurring).

Any help would be appreciated.

The Unity version is 2019.1.1f1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR

What you are doing wrong is that you are expecting the wrong physics behavior from the apply force function. That function does what it says, it applies force. It changes the object velocity instantaneously adding to it. The force mode for 2d bodies only tells the engine to consider the object's mass or not.

The problem is the naming Unity uses, AddForce doesn't "add" the force, it just applies the force for a single frame. In the following frames, all forces are zero again. If you want to keep the force, just create your own vector in your script, modify it, and apply it to the object every frame using AddForce.

---

how are you?

I have created a sample project to reproduce your issue but I couldn't reproduce the velocity staying fixed as you said. I'm not sure how you set up your scene so I made some assumptions. You probably have disabled either gravity on your object or friction, since you are reporting that the velocity is increased.

Acceleration, on the other hand, is a constant force being applied, think of it. If your car is still, and you push it for a short amount of time, the car will move then stop. If you keep pushing on the other hand, adding more and more force, the car will move faster and faster. Now think about your environment, you have a frictionless object. Every time you press Q you add a small force to it. It moves to the right a bit faster but with a constant speed (there is no force to change its velocity).

Here is what you'd want to do. Instead of adding the force only in the frame you pressed Q, add while you are pressing Q. This is what you want to do:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    time += Time.deltaTime;
    if (time > 0.5)
    {
        Debug.Log("Velocity magnitude = " + rigidbody2D.velocity.magnitude);
        time = 0;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
    {
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(speedMultiplier * Time.fixedTime * Vector2.right, ForceMode2D.Force);
    }
}
```

Another problem is the naming Unity uses, AddForce doesn't "add" the force, it just applies the force for a single frame. In the following frames all forces are zero again. If you want to keep the force, just create your own vector in your script, modify it, and apply it to the object every frame using AddForce.

Also, see that I changed Update to FixedUpdate? In Unity, you are recommended to apply all physics changes in that method instead. Update runs as much as it can (once every frame if possible), fixed update instead runs only after the physics thread is done. This means you are not spending CPU time telling the object to move every frame, and instead you are waiting for the physics to be synchronized.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion and your tip about FixedUpdate. Unfortunately the problem persists just with different numbers (I didn't use speedMultiplier, so it's like speedMultiplier = 1). I was assuming "force" means the same things it does in physics. Newton's 2nd law states F=m*a, so with m=1 I expected to have F=a. Maybe the force is applied only for one frame? How do I make it keep the force I added then? By the way, ForceMode2D.Force is the default value. Increasing Gravity Scale (originally 0) adds acceleration downards but doesn't change the x-axis behavior.

Comment: I just supposed you didn't have gravity since you reported your object was moving at a constant rate. If you had gravity and a floor, you'd have friction that would counter that movement.

Comment: I'm using GetKey instead of GetKeyDown. Try to hold Q ;)

Comment: Also what F=m.a means is that the instantaneous force of an object can be calculated as its mass times its acceleration. It doesn't mean force is equal to acceleration. At a given instant, the amount of force an object is subject to can be calculated by that expression.

Comment: I included a screenshot of the RigidBody settings which shows the Gravity Scale is set to 0. I don't have a floor, but that's really besides the point. Gravity pulls down, I'm adding a force to the right, which is orthogonal to it so the two operate independently. Friction only lessens active forces. The problem here is that `AddForce` is not adding a physical force to the body to begin with. Having something to resist the force I'm trying to add certainly isn't gonna help anything.

Comment: What F=m*a means is that the sum of all forces on a body at a given time gives a vector in the same direction as that body's acceleration at that time, perhaps with a different magnitude (the difference in scale being the body's mass). As long as the sum of forces on a body is not 0 it has acceleration. I'm adding a force. I'm not adding a countering force. The sum of forces should not be zero. So there should be acceleration. There isn't. Either the force gets removed on its own or the physics system is not emulating Newtonian physics, neither of which I think is true, thus my question here.

Comment: Using `GetKey` instead of `GetKeyDown` only makes the additions to velocity happen faster. The object still has a fixed speed when I'm not holding the Q key down, which shouldn't be the case if it has a non-zero force applied to it.

Comment: As I have said before, I only considered gravity because I wanted to understand why your object was not behaving as a normal physics object would. Inertia was keeping its speed so THIS is why I said your object was frictionless. I have never said anything about applying friction. I was just trying to understand your setup (that is not possible using a single screenshot).

Comment: Also, you don't seem to understand how engines work or game loops. You are not "adding" a force to anything, you are applying a force to an object for a single frame. That force is not "stored" anywhere. If you want that behavior, just store a vector and sum your force to it, than apply that vector every frame to the object as a force.

Comment: "which shouldn't be the case if it has a non-zero" It has no forces applied to it. You are only applying the force in the frame Q is pressed. Just read my answer, it is all there.

Comment: Wait a minute. Are you saying that every frame starts with all physical forces at 0 for every object? I assumed that AddForce adds a force to that object and is applied from that point on. If that's the case then it explains what happens perfectly. That kind of information should really be in the function documentation though. =\

Comment: Exactly, the force is added instantaneously and not stored on the object. If you want to store the force, just store a vector and add to it, applying it to the object every fixed update.

Comment: OK, that explains it. Thank you. I'll add another answer with just that bit since that's the explanation, and credit you for it of course. =)

Comment: No problem ;) . Can you mark my answer as the correct answer? I'll add the resolution there.

Comment: Sure. Just please move the second paragraph you wrote there to the top with a "TL;DR" header and separator after it so that it's easy for people with the same problem to see the point without reading everything.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's going to add enough force to the object to get it into motion. Normally you need to multiply your direction by a "force" multiple. Try something like `rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.right * 1000);`. That is, intentianally, probably way too much force but at least you'll know it's moving.

Comment: I just did that and got the same result just with different numbers. This time the velocity magnitude went up from 0 to 120 then increased by 140 each time I pressed Q (120 -> 260 -> 400 -> 540 -> 680). It only changed when I hit the Q key. Honestly I didn't expect otherwise, since my first experiment showed it *was* moving, albeit slowly. The velocity changed, but only in fixed values, like I explained. Thank you for your suggestion though.